# ios code for CATransition works only the first time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, catransition

I use this code to make the transition from one view to another in ios sdk but it is working only the first time, when i return back to the previous view it does not work although the code is triggered...

UIView *currentView = self.viewController1.view;

```
// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view view
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

// remove the current view and replace with myView1
[currentView setHidden:TRUE];//hide previous view diladi to tabviewcontroller
self.viewController1=[[MyFriendProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFriendProfile" bundle:nil];
[theWindow addSubview:self.viewController1.view];
[currentView setHidden:FALSE]; 
// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView2"];
```

Any help Appreciated!

Comment: I've just tried your sample and it looks like working for me. The only thing i did, is not using hiding of the views, but just use addSubview: method and don't forget to call removeFromSuperview method, when you're returning back to the 1st view from the 2nd one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer here is the code...

//get viewcontroller1 view

UIView *currentView = self.viewController1.view;

```
// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view view
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

// remove the current view and replace with myView1
[currentView setHidden:TRUE];//hide previous view diladi to tabviewcontroller


MyFriendProfile *test1=[[MyFriendProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFriendProfile" bundle:nil];


[theWindow addSubview:test1.view];


// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```